# Create a listener for Siri

Tags: swift, function, text, listener, siri

I'm at the beginning with swift 3 and I want to ask a questions?It's possible create a listener for Siri?
I mean , a functions that is a loop and is waiting for Siri, and when the user speaks with Siri, my listener need to capture the text and do something.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Siri API doesn't work this way.

If you want to use Siri, please read the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/

On the other hand if you only want Speech-To-Text, without Siri functionalities, you can implement it in your app using `SFSpeechRecognizer`. A fully working example is here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html